# How can I change the css code of a script file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script code

```
<script src="http://www.tgju.org/webservice/global/snippet-loader.php?token=webservice&items=mesghal,geram18,sekeb,sekee,nim,rob,gerami,price_dollar_rl,price_eur,price_aed,price_gbp,price_omr&opts=diff,time&placeholder=tgju-data"></script><div id="tgju-data"></div>
```

i want to change or deactivate css code (table,thead,th,text-align) in this code, because this css code crash another css codes!

Comment: You need access to the server at www.tgju.org, it is what is injecting blocks into your page.

Comment: You need to overwrite styles in the script,for that you can use !important

Comment: if you can tell when the script finishes doing its thing ... `document.querySelector('#tgju-data>style').remove();` where `tgju-data` is the placeholder name found here `&placeholder=tgju-data` and obviously refers to `<div id="tgju-data"></div>`